# Text written in Chinese/Japanese using fstream and not reading file correctly

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use `cin` to input user text (In normal text) to a txt file using fstream. But the text comes out as Chinese characters, and when read again it shows me random letters of the alphabet.

```
char entry[10000];
std::fstream file;

file.open ("a1bc3.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::in );

if (file.is_open()){
    std::cin >> entry;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Failed to open.\n" ;
}

file << entry << std::endl;

std::cout << "\n\n" ;
char output[10000] ;
file >> output;

std::cout << output << "\n\n" ;

file.close();
return 0;
```

When I input "Hello" it outputs "\210D"in the terminal, and "效汬੯" in the txt file.
I read online about Unicode but it's all quite confusing.

Comment: Maybe encoding mismatch. Try saving your text file as system default encoding. Also check that your stdout terminal can print Chinese character.

Comment: @ikh I just opened it in word with Unicode (UTF-8), and it worked thanks. It loaded the "Hello" but I still don't know how to get it to read "Hello" in the terminal.

Comment: Nothing related to the problem but are you sure about char arrays? Why not std::string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're printing the contents of uninitialized memory because you are not actually reading anything into your `output` array.

`std::fstream` has a single read-write position.  When you write to a file, that read-write position is left positioned directly after the data you just wrote.  When you later attempt to read from `file`, you get nothing, because the position you're reading from is *after* the data you wrote.  Since there's nothing to read, no data is written into `output`, and you end up printing the contents of uninitialized memory.

To make it work, you need to seek back to the beginning of the file after writing to it.  Simply call `file.seekg(0);` somewhere between `file << entry` and `file >> output`.

Answer (score 0):

I do python and c# but it seems when you are reading the file you are not specifying the encoding try

```
std::string path = TEXT_FILE_PATH;
std::string utf8Content = readFile(path);
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> utfconv;
std::wstring utf16LeContent = utfconv.from_bytes(utf8Content);
```

so in your case save it in a variable and do the conversion